# cloning magento website issues

Tags: magento

The idea is this: I have 2 dedicated servers (an old one and new one), I have to transfer a magento website from old server to new server via Plesk. Transferring is fine and the website works on a new server with a temporary domain (tempdomain.com) for testing purposes, however I do have this issue:

When I try to log on to admin area of a clone:

```
tempdomain.com/admin
```

I get redirected to

```
realdomain/admin
```

How do I log on to the cloned version (tempdomain.com)? I assume I have to edit some file, but I can't find which, since there are thousands, string searching through them is futile.

UPDATE: the new website has it's own (cloned) database

Comment: going through the log file of newdomain will help you out the redirecting stuff.. go through apache or whatever server log it has.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The table you are looking for is `core_config_data`. I am assuming the new tempdomain.com has its own database.

This [link](http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/update_site_url_in_core_config_data) tells you what to do.